# $\frac{a^{2}-1}{b+1}+\frac{b^{2}-1}{a+1}$ an integer $\Rightarrow \frac{a^{2}-1}{b+1}$ and $\frac{b^{2}-1}{a+1}$ are integers.

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

If $\frac{a^{2}-1}{b+1}+\frac{b^{2}-1}{a+1}$ is an integer, prove that also $\frac{a^{2}-1}{b+1}$ and $\frac{b^{2}-1}{a+1}$ are integers.

By doing the math, I get $\frac{(a-1)(a+1)^{2}+(b-1)(b+1)^{2}}{(a+1)(b+1)}$ is an integer which means that $(a+1)(b+1)$ divides $(a-1)(a+1)^{2}+(b-1)(b+1)^{2}$.

but I don't know how to continue.

By the way, this is not homework or anything. I just found it in a book.

Comment: Try proving that the sum of an integer and a non integer is a non integer and then prove that statement by proving the contrapositive

Comment: @AirMike All integers can be written as the sum of two rational numbers.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Answer (score 4):

The problem states that, for some natural numbers $a$ and $b$, there's an integer $i$ where

$$\frac{a^2 - 1}{b + 1} + \frac{b^2 - 1}{a + 1} = i \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

If the first term is an integer, say $\frac{a^2 - 1}{b + 1} = j$, then $\frac{b^2 - 1}{a + 1} = i - j$ is also an integer. Doing the same thing with the second term instead shows that if either term is an integer, the other one is as well.

Assume neither left side term in \eqref{eq1A} is an integer. As you did, combining the terms using a common denominator gives

$$\frac{(a - 1)(a + 1)^{2} + (b - 1)(b + 1)^{2}}{(a + 1)(b + 1)} = i  \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since $a + 1 \mid (a - 1)(a + 1)^{2}$, this means $a + 1 \mid (b - 1)(b + 1)^{2} = (b + 1)(b^2 - 1)$. However, since it's assumed $a + 1 \not\mid b^2 - 1$, this means there's a prime $p$ where, using the [$p$-adic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) function, we have

$$\nu_{p}(a + 1) \gt \nu_{p}(b^2 - 1) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

but

$$\nu_{p}(a + 1) \le \nu_{p}((b + 1)(b^2 - 1)) \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

This means $p \mid b + 1$. Define

$$\nu_{p}(a + 1) = k_1 \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

$$\nu_{p}(b + 1) = k_2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

If $p \neq 2$, then $p \not\mid b - 1$ and $p \not\mid a - 1$. Thus, \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$k_1 \gt k_2 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

Since $\nu_{p}((a - 1)(a + 1)^2) = 2k_1$ and $\nu_{p}((b - 1)(b + 1)^2) = 2k_2$, this means with the numerator of \eqref{eq2A},

$$\nu_{p}((a - 1)(a + 1)^{2} + (b - 1)(b + 1)^{2}) = 2k_2 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

However, with the denominator,

$$\nu_{p}((a + 1)(b + 1)) = k_1 + k_2 \gt 2k_2 \tag{9}\label{eq9A}$$

Thus, the fraction can't be an integer. Since it is an integer, this means the assumption $p \neq 2$ must be incorrect, i.e., $p = 2$. Thus, $a$ and $b$ are odd, with $p \mid a - 1$ and $p \mid b - 1$. Define

$$\nu_{p}(a - 1) = m_1 \tag{10}\label{eq10A}$$

$$\nu_{p}(b - 1) = m_2 \tag{11}\label{eq11A}$$

Using \eqref{eq6A} and \eqref{eq11A} in \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$k_1 \gt k_2 + m_2 \tag{12}\label{eq12A}$$

Note the same arguments as above could have been used to check $b + 1$ not dividing into $a^2 - 1$, with it also reaching the conclusion the prime involved must be $2$. Thus, this would give \eqref{eq12A} but with the $1$ and $2$ indices switched around, i.e.,

$$k_2 \gt k_1 + m_1 \tag{13}\label{eq13A}$$

Combining \eqref{eq12A} and \eqref{eq13A} gives

$$k_1 \gt k_2 + m_2 \gt (k_1 + m_1) + m_2 \implies 0 \gt m_1 + m_2 \tag{14}\label{eq14A}$$

This is not possible since $m_1$ and $m_2$ must be positive integers. Thus, the original assumption of the two left terms in \eqref{eq1A} not being integers must be incorrect, i.e., they are both integers.

Comment: John Omielan thank you for your solution! By the way, if anyone thinks of any alternative method, without the use of this p-adic order function (which I do not understand), I would appreciate it!

Comment: @Harry Yes, it can be done much more simply using only the rational root test - see my answer.

Comment: @John I haven't had time to read your proof, but likely it generalizes to show by p-adic valuations the Remark in my answer, You might consider proving that instead, since that would likely be more instructive (or, you could prove the full-blown  Rational Root Test that way)

Answer (score 4):

Call the fractions $r,s.\,$ Note $\,rs = (a\!-\!1)(b\!-\!1) := m\in \Bbb Z,\,$ so if $\,r\!+\!s = n\in\Bbb Z\,$ then $\,r,s\,$ are roots of $\, (x-r)(x-s)\, =\ \color{#c00}1\cdot x^2 - n\, x + m\,$
so $\,r,s\in \Bbb Z\,$ by [Rational Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/658058/242) (i.e. if $\,c/d\,$ is a reduced rational root then $\,d\mid\color{#c00}1,\,$ so $\,d\!=\!1,\,$ so $\,c/d\in\Bbb Z)$.

Generally this shows $\,\bbox[5px,border:1px solid #c00]{\text{two rationals with integer sum & product must be integers}}$